# What is the difference between Windows Credentials and Generic Credentials?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, credentials, credentials-manager

I have noticed that when I add credentials for a shared drive as `Generic Credentials` instead of `Windows Credentials` to the `Windows Credentials Manager` they don't work, but when they are added as the latter they do work.

Why is this? What are their differences?

Keep in mind the credentials I'm adding are like in this example:

> Address: \\192.168.0.1
>
> User: user
>
> Password: password

Comment: _Generic_ are not specific to an application [as far as the Credentials Manager is concerned], while _Windows_ ones are specific to Windows. So if the application which is using them is Windows, it has to be _Windows credentials_ specifically, not the loosely-defined _Generic_ ones.

Comment: So does that mean that `Generic Credentials` won't ever work to access a shared drive that is accessed like in the example?

Comment: if using Windows Explorer (or more generally Windows Shell API), no it won't work; it might work for other application accessing the same share, however, if that application implements its own credential checking instead of relying on Windows API.

Answer (score 2):

According to the link: [Kinds of Windows 10 Credentials](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/kinds-of-credentials), the `Generic Credentials` are used by the applications for authentication and security, directly, without delegating `Windows Operating System` to do that.

The `Windows Operating System level credentials` or the `Domain Credentials` are used by the OS and then authenticated by the `Local Security Authority`.

The `Certificate Credentials` are credentials that `Azure Active Directory` allow applications to authenticate within applications using their own certificates.

See: [Active Directory Certificate Credentials](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials)
and [How to add a certificate to the Windows Credential Manager?](https://serverfault.com/a/580071/510074)

There are also other credentials, that are used by devices so that they do not have to authenticate again and again.

Have a great day ahead!